# How to permute values of pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
Datetime           Supply   Price
2019-02-01 12:00   10       2.0
2019-02-01 12:00   10       1.0
2019-02-01 12:00   0        5.0
2019-02-01 12:00   10       1.0
2019-02-01 12:00   0        2.0
2019-02-01 12:00   10       4.0
2019-02-01 12:00   0        5.0
```

The sum of `Supply` is 40. I need to permute `Suppy` 10 in order to assign them to higher values of `Price`, while `Supply` 0 should occur at lower values of `Price`.

This is the expected result:

```
Datetime           Supply   Price
2019-02-01 12:00   10       2.0
2019-02-01 12:00   0        1.0
2019-02-01 12:00   10       5.0
2019-02-01 12:00   0        1.0
2019-02-01 12:00   0        2.0
2019-02-01 12:00   10       4.0
2019-02-01 12:00   10       5.0
```

Any clues how to do it?

Comment: Is the logic to assign the sorted Supply values to the sorted Price values? (i.e. what happens when supply isn't just 2 values, only one of which is non-zero)

Comment: @ALollz: this should be a maximization task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `argsort`

- Multiply by negative one as a convenient way to switch the sort
- Use `argsort` to track the positions of where to drop my values
- Create `b` to house my permuted values
- Populate `b` with a sorted version of `Supply`
- Assign back to `df`

---

```
a = df.Price.mul(-1).to_numpy().argsort()
b = np.empty_like(df.Supply)

b[a] = df.Supply.sort_values(ascending=False)

df.loc[:, 'Supply'] = b

df

           Datetime  Supply  Price
0  2019-02-01 12:00      10    2.0
1  2019-02-01 12:00       0    1.0
2  2019-02-01 12:00      10    5.0
3  2019-02-01 12:00       0    1.0
4  2019-02-01 12:00       0    2.0
5  2019-02-01 12:00      10    4.0
6  2019-02-01 12:00      10    5.0
```

---

There is room to optimize this code but the general idea is there.

Answer (score 2):

Without any constraint other than you cannot combine "Supply", sort each separately. I maintain the row-binding of Datetime and Price, which would be evident if they weren't all the same date:

```
pd.concat([df['Supply'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True),
           df[['Datetime', 'Price']].sort_values('Price').reset_index(drop=True)],
          axis=1) 

   Supply          Datetime  Price
0       0  2019-02-01 12:00    1.0
1       0  2019-02-01 12:00    1.0
2       0  2019-02-01 12:00    2.0
3      10  2019-02-01 12:00    2.0
4      10  2019-02-01 12:00    4.0
5      10  2019-02-01 12:00    5.0
6      10  2019-02-01 12:00    5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you sort `df` by `Price`, then change `Supply` to the sorted supply values, it should do what I think you want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Supply':[10,10,0,10,0,10,0],
                   'Price': [2., 1.,5.,1.,2.,4.,5.]})

df.sort_values('Price', inplace=True)
df['Supply'] = df['Supply'].sort_values().values

   Supply  Price
1       0   1.00
3       0   1.00
0       0   2.00
4      10   2.00
5      10   4.00
2      10   5.00
6      10   5.00
```

You can re-sort to get back in the original order if you need to.

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

   Supply  Price
0       0   2.00
1       0   1.00
2      10   5.00
3       0   1.00
4      10   2.00
5      10   4.00
6      10   5.00
```